# How to make this chapter title?

Tags: chapters

[image]I have tried with tikzpicture, but the problem I could not make the alignment from right to left. so once I add the second node the number is shifted to the left.

Then I tried with:

```
 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\flushright \normalfont}
  {\fontseries{b}\fontsize{80}{100}\selectfont \textcolor{chapnumberbg}\thechapter}
  {-30pt}
  {\Huge #1 \vspace{1ex}}
```

but I didn't manage to make same spacing between the header and the chapter number and between the chapter and the first text line.

my results with the space:
[image]

I solved it, and here is the complete solution:

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[a4paper, layout=b5paper, twoside,
    verbose, textheight=200mm, top=22mm, textwidth=133mm,
    nofoot, showframe, showcrop]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\definecolor{chapnumberbg}{RGB}{26,40,105}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\flushright \normalfont} % format
  {\fontseries{b}\fontsize{80}{60}\selectfont \textcolor{chapnumberbg}\thechapter} % label
  {-20pt} % sep
  {\Huge #1} % before-code
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}


\begin{document}


    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \chapter{Introduction}
    \blindtext

    \bibliography{main}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please post a small, yet complete, code, that we can play with?

Comment: I just updated the code. It is working. I just didn't manage to reduce the space between the header and the chapter title and the chapter with the first line

Comment: The spacing between chapter title and beginning of text can be changed via the third argument of  `\titlespacing`. As to the header, what do you mean exactly? There's no header on the first page of a chapter.

Comment: the distance between the beginning of the page and the title of the chapter